# impossible to install office after crash during office installation

Tags: microsoft-office, installation, crash

I'm on windows 7 pro I was installing office 2010 beta when my computer crashed, so I had to hit the reset button after this I am unable to install any kind of office (I tried 2007 also), I also tried to stop the office file services manually and try to install but no luck.
Anybody knows what can I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have Windows System Restore enabled? That's my first step.

Microsoft has a tool to remove Office completely. I don't know if it works on newer versions though, and I wouldn't know where to start looking.

<strike>There's also that msizap.exe tool that might be able to help. You can Google for that.</strike> (Ignore this one. I meant the [Windows Installer Cleanup Tool](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290301).)

Failing that, nuke the Office sections in the Registry, but make sure you back up before you try that.

Comment: that didn't helped

Comment: Which part didn't help?

Comment: cleanup tool, but now i'm trying to nuke all the register references

Comment: i cleaned the registry with windows 7 manager registry cleanup and still can't install office

Comment: I'm not familiar with Windows 7 Manager Registry cleanup. I was specifically referring to *regedit.exe*.

Comment: What exactly is your error message? Is it the same every time?

Comment: yes, it's the same, it tells me that an error occurred during installation

Comment: Does it prompt you for "Repair" or "Remove"? If so, try both of those. I have seen some sites saying you must reinstall the .NET Framework, which might be difficult on Windows 7, but worth a shot.

Comment: I've reinstalled  windows :)

Comment: That would be my next suggestion :-)